# fmt::format() with chrono local date is different than with iostream

Tags: c++, c++20, fmt

To be portable, while I'm using the `{fmt}` library for formatting dates and times, I encounter a small problem with printing times. Probably `fmt` treats time as local time, whereas `<iostream>` prints time as UTC?

Minimal example:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <fmt/chrono.h>

int main(){ 
    using TimePoint = std::chrono::system_clock::time_point;

    TimePoint localTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();

    auto localTimeStr = fmt::format("{:%F %T}", localTime);

    std::cout << localTimeStr << std::endl
              << localTime;

     return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2023-03-15 21:47:46
2023-03-15 20:47:46.0631142
```

I'm using MSVC 19.34, fmt 9.1.0

How to set up `fmt` to format time correctly in this case?

I read the documentation, but I don't see any solution. I expect to print the same value for the `<iostream>` and `fmt` strings.
How to format time to be printed in always in UTC using fmt lib?

Comment: Works wit gcc: https://godbolt.org/z/E1KoMjr46

Comment: @joergbrech I'm assuming he's experiencing the problem because he's local timezone is not UTC

Comment: @joergbrech [not really](https://godbolt.org/z/x7EodYf7K).

Answer (score 3):

`std::chrono::system_clock` represents UTC time.

When you print the clock with `fmt::format()` using the `"{:%F %T}"` format, the output is locale-independent. However, when you print the clock with `operator<<`, that is equivalent to printing it with `std::format()` using the `{:L%F %T}` format and the `ostream`'s currently assigned locale.

Comment: From you response I understand that using `fmt::format("{:%F %T}", sth);` is locale independent - so it should print in UTC time? But in code which i show you fmt prints time in local, iostream prints in UTC. So it's no clear for my why?

Answer (score 0):

It is non-conformance of the `fmt` library.

By the standard, `std::chrono::system_clock::time_point` is a point in Unix time, which is very similar to UTC time but without the leap seconds. If `%Z` is used, the formatter [should insert the string `"UTC"` in the output](https://eel.is/c++draft/time.format#8). The `fmt` library [does something else](https://godbolt.org/z/G36qPGYhh).

The standard specifies formatters for other clocks such as `utc_clock` and `tai_clock`, but `fmt` [doesn't seem to implement those] as of now.(https://godbolt.org/z/ch3T4TnK8).

For maximum portability, [use `std::gmtime`](https://godbolt.org/z/5dnMGbWbP).